# Нужная ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

После оплаты человеком мебели для кухни (,) товар он не получил и был проигнорирован.

Answer (score 1):

Нет, запятая здесь не нужна. Это не ССП, фраза *После оплаты человеком мебели для кухни* не нуждается в отделении запятой от следующей за ней части предложения.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая не нужна, но не потому что "не ССП".

Сочетание с предлогом "после" стоит с абсолютном начале предложения.

Будь иной порядок слов, обособление было бы необходимо:

*Покупатель, после оплаты мебели для кухни, товар не получил, его заказ был проигнорирован.*

[**источник**](http://orthographia.ru/punctum_uk.php?rid=192)